# Why Rails defaults creation to a POST on collection in HTML form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

When generating a scaffold, by default the `new_resource_path` generates a form that will submit to `resources_path`.

This makes total sense in a RESTful mentality.

But, given that the generated material does not uses it as a REST resource, why does it POST to the collection path?

When the resource is successfully created, Rails will redirect to the created resource path. When any error occurs, Rails will render the `new` template that will present the errors (generated by scaffolding).

This seems fine, except that when any errors occurs when trying to create the resource, the URL will change to the collection path. This means that if user tries to refresh the page, it will not see the creation form. If the application does not allow listing for this resource, a routing error may happen. In case the application uses any type of authorization and the current user does not has the required authorization to list stuff, it may see a forbidden.

I see Rails scaffold generator as something the community agrees to be the standard way to do basic CRUD in it. So, why this behavior?

It seems that by keeping a purist RESTful resources approach we are breaking user experience a bit.

To see an example of this, just create a new Rails application, scaffold a new entity and try to create it with some validation errors.

```
$ rails new example
$ cd example
$ rails generate scaffold note text
# edit app/models/note.rb
  class Note < ApplicationRecord
   validates :text, length: { minimum: 10 }
  end
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails server
# go to localhost:3000/notes/new
# click 'Create Note'
# see the error
# hit browser's refresh button
# now you are listing notes, and not creating one
```

If you think "this should not harm a real application". I've come up with this when writing tests for authentication.

My application is using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and fails for this test:

```
test 'new user should not be able to register with wrong password confirmation' do
  email = 'newuser@newdomain.com'
  password = 'little$secret'
  password_confirmation = 'big$secret'

  visit new_user_registration_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: email
  fill_in 'Password', with: password
  fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: password_confirmation

  assert_no_difference ->{ User.count } do
    click_on 'Sign up'
  end

  assert page.has_content?("Password confirmation doesn't match Password")
  # FAILS:
  assert_equal new_user_registration_path, current_path
end
```

What this means in real life: When user tries to create an account, submit an invalid form, see the error and hit refresh, it is on an invalid path as the resource does not support listing (i.e. `/users`).

To make that last assertion pass, I had to overwrite the default Devise view to submit the form to `/users/sign_up` instead of just `/users` and to add a new route to call `create` when a POST is made to this URL. Then I realized that this will happen to any controller following the RESTful Resource approach, unless developers create this new route and use a custom URL for submitting creation forms.

Also, the "purist RESTful Resource approach" doesn't seem to be so purist. When you submit your form with invalid data, the POST will result in a 200 OK rendering an HTML with errors, instead of a 400 Bad Request. So, why not submit the form to the same URL the form exists in?

My bet is that I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> But, given that the generated material does not uses it as a REST 
>   resource, why does it POST to the collection path?
>   So, why not submit the form to the same URL the form exists in?

Because the rails conventions embrace statelessness.
The form that you see when a `create` fails shows the result of a POST request. It is not meant to be repeated - or shared.

You could potentially have `POST /notes/create` and create a `GET /notes/create` route so that it would show the form after a refresh - but is that a good design from a framework point of view? I would say no.

Forms that POST back to the same URL can give a bad user experience - like the "Confirm form submission" dialog when you hit the back button. This is actually worse than the scenario you are painting up as it can lead to unexpected consequences for the user.

> I see Rails scaffold generator as something the community agrees to be
>   the standard way to do basic CRUD in it.

The rails scaffold command is a rapid prototyping tool. They are not meant as the authoritative source of the "right" way to do rails nor does the community hold them as the word of god.

> Also, the "purist RESTful Resource approach" doesn't seem to be so
>   purist.

The Rails community is not very purist. If anything its quite pragmatic and aims towards embracing concepts like REST but with a focus on developer convenience and "should just work".

> When you submit your form with invalid data, the POST will
>   result in a 200 OK rendering an HTML with errors, instead of a 400 Bad
>   Request.

This is pragmatism, back in the day Internet Explorer would do all kinds of annoying things when given 4XX response codes. 200 OK guarantees the client will render the response - although it is tecnically wrong.

Answer (score -2):

> This seems fine, except that when any errors occurs when trying to
>   create the resource, the URL will change to the collection path. This
>   means that if user tries to refresh the page, it will not see the
>   creation form.

I don't get you : If you refresh the page, it will just re-POST the same parameters and so show the same form with errors. I just re-checked that.

> If the application does not allow listing for this resource, a routing
>   error may happen. In case the application uses any type of
>   authorization and the current user does not has the required
>   authorization to list stuff, it may see a forbidden.

So, a user would not be allowed, for example, to view a list of posts, but it would allowed to create a new one ?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 46.0.1. Browser does not re-submit the form on refresh after a 200 OK response, but does re-submit if you refresh on a connection error (for example). This point is equal to both sides, POSTing to the collection or not. So, when user tries to refresh on collection, controller will try to list; when user tries to refresh on "new" page, controller will reset the form.

To the second point: yes, an application may allow you to create and not to list resources. I gave an example at the question: you may create an account, but you shouldn't be able to list accounts.